# modify the woocommerce customer email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have a website that uses woocommerce as a shopping car, usually they customer can choose different types of delivery, one of them is Local Pickup, we want the address where you can pick up your items and the time when you can pick it up to be sent in the email that the customer receive after he check out, but only if they choose local pick up these information will be sent to avoid confusion to the customer.

any idea where i can modify the text that goes out with the email, ill include a screen shot to know what i am talking about
[email screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lOPv.jpg)

Comment: Hello :) havent heard you for a while. Did my code help to solve your problem? If yes could you please mark my question as the right answer? :) thx

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can not do this with any e-mail edits because of woocommerce emails are set for the order statuses, not to the shipping methods. You could do it with code implementation into your theme's functions.php file.

Explanation: You need to add action before woocommerce email order table and set function for this action. In your function you will track your order's shipping method and if it match with local pickup then it adds extra text before the order table.

Do not forget to change this to your custom text echo `'<h2 class="email-upsell-title">Local pickup instructions</h2><p class="email-upsell-p">Your text goes here for the local pickup info</p>';`

UPDATE

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'localpickup_extra_info', 10, 4 );

function localpickup_extra_info( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
   if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {
   foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $shipping_item ){
   $shipping_rate_id = $shipping_item->get_method_id();
   $method_array = explode(':', $shipping_rate_id );
   $shipping_method_id = reset($method_array);

   if( 'local_pickup' == $shipping_method_id ){  
      echo '<h2 class="heading-title">Local pickup instructions</h2><p class="local-text">Your text goes here for the local pickup info</p>'; //change this
      break;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but i tried it with different shipping methods and it still show the local pickup instructions, anyway for now it will do but if there is away it wont show if the customer pick a different shipping method that would be great :)

Comment: @AlexA.H try now